# Use dropbox to select database query

Tags: php

I want to sort my mysql-database on different fields.
I have 3 fields and i want to change the sort-method using a dropdown in my form.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['order']))   {
echo "Du har valgt <b>".$_POST['order']."</b><br><br>";
if ($_POST['order'] = "title")  {
$tur = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM $tours ORDER BY title ASC"; //mising doubleqoute
}
else
if ($_POST['order'] = "dato")  {
$tur = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM $tours ORDER BY dato DESC;
}
else 
if ($_POST['order'] = "km")  {
$tur = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM $tours ORDER BY km DESC;
}
}

 if(mysql_num_rows($tur) > 0) {
          while($a = mysql_fetch_object($tur)) {
           $turid = $a -> id;
           $turd =  $a -> dato;
           ...
 }


?>
<form action="" method="post">
Your sort:
<select name="order" onchange="javascript: submit()">
<option>---</option>
<option value="title">title/option>
<option value ="dato">dato</option>
<option value="km">km</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When i choose a value in my dropdown i only get the result of the first field: title  -no matter what choose i have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close your statement:

```
$tur = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM $tours ORDER BY title ASC;
```

Needs to be:

```
$tur = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM $tours ORDER BY title ASC");
```

The `")` is missing from the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try with == instead of = in all if statement:

**if($_POST['order'] == "title") ...**

Hope this helps.

regards

Answer (score 0):

change your  `=`  to `==`

```
$order_value = "";
if(isset($_POST['order']))   
{
    $order_value  = $_POST['order'];
    echo "Du har valgt <b>".$order_value."</b><br><br>";
    if ($order_value == "title")  {
    $tur = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM $tours ORDER BY title ASC");
    }
    elseif ($order_value == "dato")  {
    $tur = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM $tours ORDER BY dato DESC");
    }
    else if ($order_value == "km")  {
    $tur = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM $tours ORDER BY km DESC");
    }
}
```

`=` is assignment operator

`==` is comparison operator

this code will do the trick

for option to be selected after submit

```
<select name="order" onchange="javascript: submit()">
<option>---</option>
<option value="title" <?php echo ($order_value!="" && $order_value=="title")? "selected": "" ;?>>title/option>
<option value ="dato" <?php echo ($order_value!="" && $order_value=="dato")? "selected": "" ;?>>dato</option>
<option value="km" <?php echo ($order_value!="" && $order_value=="km")? "selected": "" ;?>>km</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That did it. But when I work with my data it dissapear from me. (the selection does not keep). How do i keep the selection until the next selection in the dropdown?